# Koa-router issue with / and /signin

Tags: javascript, node.js, koa

/index.js:

```
//... code
import routes from './routes/bind';
app.use(routes.routes(), routes.allowedMethods());
//... code
```

/routes/bind.js:

```
'use strict';

import KoaRouter from 'koa-router';
const router = new KoaRouter();

// routes requests
import routes from './routes';
router.use(`/`, routes.routes(), routes.allowedMethods());

export default router;
```

/routes/routes.js:

```
'use strict';

import KoaRouter from 'koa-router';
const router = new KoaRouter();

// home page
router.get(`/`, async function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.body = 'home page';
});

// sign in page
router.get(`/signin`, async function(ctx, next) {
    ctx.body = 'sign in page';
});

export default router;
```

`127.0.0.1:3000` works (displays home page)

`127.0.0.1:3000/signin` does not work (displays 404)

`127.0.0.1:3000/signin` isn't working for some reason. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently `127.0.0.1:3000//signin` shows the sign in page. So remove the preceding `/` from the route definition.

The reason why `127.0.0.1:3000` works correctly is that koa-router can automatically handle trailing slashes. For the home page, the route you're actually defining is `//`, but koa-router can handle this. However, for the sign in page the route is `//signin`, but koa-router can't (nor should it) handle preceding slashes.

Comment: I put the /signin in the /routes/bind.js file and it worked.